# Writing files safely (WinRT)

Tags: file-io, windows-runtime

What approach do you use to write critical app files like settings, configuration files, user files in WinRT, or in general?

To illustrate my concern - in my app I am saving the list of user selected data sources as a JSON file. In case the user updates the list and saves it, I just overwrite the current file with the new JSON serialized list. But if the app were killed from the task manager or the computer lost power in that very moment when the file is being written, it would stay in an inconsistent state and would probably cause the app not to launch or the user would definitely lose data.

I considered writing into a different file and then swap them when finished. Is this solution the best one possible?

Comment: If you're worried of data loss in situations as extreme as power cut, then indeed writing to a separate file is the only way. But just so you know, most apps don't bother, and yet I bet you haven't met this issue in years. If the file is small (up to a few hundred KBs), then the probability of something interrupting the process is extremely low.

Comment: WinRT already works that way, file creation is transactional and won't be committed until the file is closed.  No need to help.  If you don't trust it for some reason, it is hard to see, then just write a temporary file and rename it afterwards.

Comment: It is true that I am probably a bit overcautious. But it is good to know that WinRT file access is built this way.